# Ayuda, no puedo ejecutar .bat externo desde mi aplicacion C# windows forms

Tags: c#

Estoy diseñando un programa en Windows Forms C# y tengo el siguiente problema:

El programa cuenta de un botón que al darle click, este ejecuta un `.bat` que esta en una ubicación de la pc.

He probado con ejecutar `.exe` de esta forma y sale perfecto
pero en el caso de los `.bat` , al darle clic al botón sale  la ventana de consola del `.bat` y rápidamente se cierra

el `.bat` independientemente funciona bien , ejecutándolo con doble click.

**Codigo del boton:**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\programas pcs\PROGRAMAS\instaladorx64.bat");

        }
```

**lineas del .bat ***

```
@echo off
color 1f
Title Instalandor nombre
echo
echo
echo --------------------------------- ------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Instalando NETFRAMEWORK 
echo.
dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64 /passive /norestart
echo.
echo.
cls
echo --------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Instalando KM-Spico
echo.
sc stop WinDefend
Activador\Activador\KMSpico_setup.exe /SILENT
echo.
echo.
cls
```

Comment: y como sabes que el .bat se ejecutó mal? ya que que si no quieres que se cierre el bat al ejecutarlo entonces al final ponle un paused

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es una suposición ya que no das muchas pistas, pero muy probablemente el problema es simplemente que el .bat no encuentra los ejecutables que trata de correr.

Debes añadir la propiedad `WorkingDirectory` apuntando a la carpeta donde están dichos ejecutables. Usa el método que te puso @marc y añade la linea donde se añade el `WorkingDirectory` (`processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(command);`):

```
static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //Esta propiedad oculta la consola
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(command);

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();

    exitCode = process.ExitCode; //Si tu bat tiene exit code lo obtendrá aquí

    process.Close();
}
```

Comment: funciono, faltaba el path.getDirectoryname(); tengo que leer mas sobre este metodo para entender que es lo que psaba , muchas gracias

Answer (score 5):

La forma mas segura de ejecutar archivos `.bat` es ejecutar la consola de windows y pasarle el comando de ejecución de ese archivo `.bat`, un ejemplo del código seria la siguiente función, pasandole como parámetro la ruta del archivo `.bat`:

```
static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //Esta propiedad oculta la consola
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();

    exitCode = process.ExitCode; //Si tu bat tiene exit code lo obtendrá aquí

    process.Close();
}
```

Deberías llamar esta funcion de la siguiente manera en tu código:

```
ExecuteCommand(@"E:\programas pcs\PROGRAMAS\instaladorx64.bat");
```

Comment: no amigo, cree la funcion executecommand, y le pase el parametro en el boton y no hace nada de nada

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR Edita tu pregunta añadiendo el código que hay en el archivo `.bat` para poder ver mejor de donde viene el problema

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y le puse el codigo del .bat

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR Como sabes que no se esta ejecutando lo que hay en el BAT? Lo tienes todo silencioso

Comment: porque al ejecutar el .bat fuera de la aplicacion se mantiene la ventana de consola abierta aunque no muestre lo que se esta instalando

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR Entonces, prueba de quitar en la función que te he puesto el `process.Close()` y al final del `.bat` pon un `pause`

Comment: No, nada, cuando le doy clic al boton no pasa nada, y tengo el panel de control abierto a ver si instala la 1ra aplicacion del bat que es winrar, y no la instala, cambie processInfo.CreateNoWindow a false y processInfo.UseShellExecute = true y ahora muetra la consola y se quita rapidamente, voy debuguear a ver si encuentro algo

Comment: @Pikoh   si lo ejecuta, pero no se por que no esta viendo el contenido del .bat,, ahora  mismo modifique el .bat y le puse pause al final, y lo ejecute desde el programa con process.Start y SI lo ejecuta, pero me sale el .bat con la pantalla > presione una tecla para continuar, o sea, solo vio el pause.

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR mira la respuesta que te he puesto a ver

Comment: @Pikoh Si puedes ejecutarlos, pero no es la mejor manera, edito el post para aclararlo